# Run sequential test files

Tags: shell-script

I have c program that I run like this:

```
./a.out t1
```

And my test files look like this all the way up to 100:

```
t1
t2
t3
```

Is there a way to run this more efficiently so I don't have to hit up and change the number every time?

Comment: With [`gnu parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) you could run `parallel ./a.out ::: t{1..100}` - not sure if you want to run them in parallel though...

Answer (score 4):

A simple loop will do the trick:

```
for i in {1..100}; do ./a.out t${i}; done
```